# How to output an array individually for each object in JSON using JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

The `for (let pet of person.pets)` does not output as expected. It is an array in the JSON. Instead of a single array, I get all the pet arrays *for all objects* in my JSON file. I just want one array per object listed in the JSON-example below.

```
{
   "name": "Nallil Keenwillow",
   "age": "32",
   "pets": [
     "Giddo",
     "Berl",
     "Jaenna"
   ]
 },
```

```js
let persons;
let pets;

async function getData() {
  persons = await $.getJSON('persons.json');
  pets = await $.getJSON('pets.json');
  renderPersonsToScreen();
}

function renderPersonsToScreen() {
  for (let person of persons) {
    $('body').append(/*html*/`
    <div class="person">
    <h1>${person.name}</h1>
    <p>Age: ${person.age}</p>
    </div>
  `);
    for (let pet of person.pets) {
      $('.person').append(/*html*/`
      <h2>${pet}</h2>
       `
      )
    }
  }
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.person').append()` appends to *all* `.person` elements. You should just append to the `person` element you just added.

```js
function renderPersonsToScreen() {
  for (let person of persons) {
    let pdiv = $( /*html*/ `
    <div class="person">
    <h1>${person.name}</h1>
    <p>Age: ${person.age}</p>
    </div>
  `);
    for (let pet of person.pets) {
      pdiv.append( /*html*/ `
      <h2>${pet}</h2>
       `)
    }
    $('body').append(pdiv);
  }
}
```